# @Url.Content not rendering as intended

Tags: html, c#-4.0

I am trying to render an image to display in my view, I build the html in my controller

```
var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
htmlBuilder.Append("<li><a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser' target='_blank'>");
htmlBuilder.Append("<img alt='Chrome' src='@Url.Content('~/Content/Images/chrome-logo.png')'>CHROME</a></li>");
```

I then put this in a session

```
Session["HTML"] = htmlBuilder.ToString();
```

Now when the we get to the view. I render it using @Html.Raw

```
@Html.Raw(Session["HTML"].ToString())
```

For some reason the rendered html looks different. Results from inspecting html in chrome debugger.

```
<li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Chrome" src="@Url.Content(" ~="" content="" images="" chrome-logo.png")"="">
        CHROME
    </a>
</li>
```

Notice @Url.Content now has = " " in it. Please help I have no idea whats going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead: `htmlBuilder.Append("<img alt='Chrome' src='@Url.Content(\"~/Content/Images/chrome-logo.png\")'>CHROME</a></li>");`

Comment: Already tried that. Thanks though. @Url.Content is not transforming the src at all. In theory the result should be 
    localhost/mylink/content/images/chrome-logo.png, 
but it stays as @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/chrome-logo.png")